# How to politely follow up on application status update?

Tags: job-offer, follow-up

I would like to obtain an update on the status of an application I made for a summer internship position (call it A). The reason is, I was given an offer for an alternative position (call it B) but I would like A better.

For context, regarding position A, I do not even know where they are standing in the application calendar; I have not been invited for an interview nor do I know whether they interview their applicants at all! For position B though, the calendar was clear from the beginning and the process moved efficiently.

In anticipation of getting an offer for position B, I contacted the recruiter for position A two weeks ago to inquire about the status of my application there. I was very open-ended in what I asked: I just requested a hint whether my application was "likely" or "unlikely" to move further and, in absence of such information, I said I would just be happy with a few precisions on their application calendar. The guy committed to come back to me within 2 days, which they didn't. Now, around one week later (that is, one week ago relative to the date of this post), I actually got the offer for position B with a dozen days to accept or decline. I therefore emailed the recruiter from position A to notify them of the update, explicitly mentioning the offer B timeframe and reiterating my initial inquiry. They acknowledged the update, said they would look into the status of my application, without providing any date. As of today (one week after this last exchange), I'm still without news from them. I have to accept or decline offer B by the end of the week.

My question is then, how to follow up as efficiently as possible with offer A recruiter? My doubts are the following:

- Given the urgency of settling with the other offer (which the recruiter knows about), is it fine to send them more than one reminder this week? Maybe one every other day?
- Did I make a mistake by mentioning the recruiter from position A about offer B? Is talking about competing offer considered taboo in the mind of some HR people? I would say not necessarily, because the recruiter for position B actively invited us to tell them about all competing deadlines, but this may be a cultural thing varying from company to company.
- How to phrase my demand politely but in a way that strongly incites the recruiter to action?
- Do you find the attitude of the recruiter professional at all? If so, what may be reasons for their behaviour? The experience of HR people may help here.

Comment: Thanks @JoeStrazzere for the advice. Unfortunately, I may find it hard to reach the right person by phone since the company happens to be a large one and the department to which I'm applying has its own processes central administration may not aware of. In case I still managed to reach someone, would you advise me to phrase my inquiry in a specific way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given the urgency of settling with the other offer (which the recruiter knows about), is it fine to send them more than one reminder this week? Maybe one every other day?

Not really. You have done all the right things so far and the ball is clearly in their court which they have already acknowledged. More reminders won't help and just come across "naggy" or "desperate".

> Did I make a mistake by mentioning the recruiter from position A about offer B? Is talking about competing offer considered taboo in the mind of some HR people? I would say not necessarily, because the recruiter for position B actively invited us to tell them about all competing deadlines, but this may be a cultural thing varying from company to company.

No mistake here. That was perfectly fine. You were open and transparent.

> How to phrase my demand politely but in a way that strongly incites the recruiter to action?

There is not much you can do here. They are apparently snagged in their own process (which unfortunately is common) and nothing you do or say will help unclogging this.

> Do you find the attitude of the recruiter professional at all? If so, what may be reasons for their behaviour? The experience of HR people may help here.

Irrelevant question, but I answer anyway. It's not particularly professional but very common. Recruiting processes are complicated, can involve many people and steps and any single point can hold up progress. This may have nothing to do with the recruiter but could also be the hiring manager, some budget approval, diversity review, etc. Internship hires are also the lowest priority, which doesn't help either.

**Summary:** You did all the right things here and there is nothing more useful you can do. Company A is moving very slow and more reminders won't help. It's very unlikely that they will make you an offer in time. This may not be a bad thing: Company B handled the recruiting process much better and chances are their inner workings for internships are much better too.

Comment: Thanks @Hilmar for the detailed answer. In particular, I didn't suspect that companies getting "snagged" in their hiring processes as you put it was that common. I also get your general point that there is not much I can do and I'd rather I moved with the other offer. Do you think it might still be acceptable to send an ultimate follow-up in last resort (that would be the third in three weeks)? Or would it do more harm than good in any case in your opinion?

Comment: I guess one a week is still fine. Just don't get your hopes up